# Pandas re-indexing with Multiindex on Index AND Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a long dataframe with these columns in this format:

```
id  gender  size    region_a_count  region_b_count  item_group
 x   m       x            x                x         x
 x   f       x            x                x         x
 x   f       x            x                x         x
 x   m       x            x                x         x
 x   f       x            x                x         x
 x   m       x            x                x         x
```

Each combination of gender, size,item_group and region is unique. So there is no need to perform an aggregation.

I want to reindex the index and columns to this type of output, with the cell values staying the same

```
                    region_a         region_b        region_c   
                    m        f       m        f      m         f
      (index of size)
item_group  1                       
            2                       
            3                       
item_group  1                       
            2                       
            3
```

That is, with index as well as columns having a multiindex. I was able to perform the part for the index by calling:

```
df.groupby(["item_group","size"])
```

But the column problem still remains.

How can I create the column multiindex from the existing dataframe?

Comment: Is possible set some values to `x` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, Its difficult to paste them nicely formatted. They are a mix of numbers and strings. They aren't relevant though, considering that each combination is unique :)

Comment: So solution working for you? If not, be free change `x` to `a`, `b`, `c` or `1`, `2`, `3` and also add it to expected output.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, didnt see that you are the same person who answered the question. Yes, solution worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(["item_group","size", "id","gender"]).unstack()
```