# Pandas, how to create an hierchical index from a set of rows

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
                    MgO    Al2O3    Li
B                   3.4    99.77    0.010 
C                    0      1        0.012
```

And I would like to transform it into.

```
                    MgO             Al2O3           Li
                   B    C          B    C         B    C
A                 3.4   0         99.77  1      0.010 0.012
```

That is, I would like to squeeze all rows into a single row, and creating an hierarchy of columns.
I can achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas re-indexing with Multiindex on Index AND Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969126/pandas-re-indexing-with-multiindex-on-index-and-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Just unstack and transpose also works:

```
df.unstack().to_frame("A").T
```

You can use [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) , then [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) the dataframe, and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) only if column order matters:

```
df.unstack().to_frame("A").T.sort_index(axis=1).reindex(columns=df.columns,level=0)
```

---

```
     MgO       Al2O3         Li       
     B    C      B    C     B      C
A  3.4  0.0  99.77  1.0  0.01  0.012
```